# Postgres Datediff

Tags: sql, postgresql, date-arithmetic

I want to have `datediff` and use that in where condition in Postgres.

I have created this query

```
select emp_id
      ,"last_date::date" - "first_date::date" as days 
  from emp 
  where "last_date::date" - "first_date::date" > 10
;
```

Is there any better solution?

Comment: Hello, I have improved question format using ` to highligh text and empty line to create new line. Correct quote for naming field in SELECT and place select in code bloc. It seems that it is your first post. I propose that you edit your question again to see what I have done and if SELECT is always conform to your first question. Caution: it is possible that my correction is visible only in 10 or 30 minutes until it is peer reviewed !

Comment: What is it you don't like about the query?

Comment: Check this link  http://www.sqlines.com/postgresql/how-to/datediff

Comment: `"last_date::date"` should be `"last_date"::date` or get rid of those dreaded double quotes alltogether